# Why is my parallized for-loop so much slower?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I tried to parallize a for-loop in Python using the multiprocessing package. The function I want to run on multiple threads is this one

```
def regression_loss(W, k, x, y):
    U = expit(x.dot(W[k].T)) - y
    return np.sum(U*U)
```

which computes the error of a multi-class regression problem for several data points `x`. `W` is a weight matrix and `y` is the target.

Currently the parallized for-loop is about 200 times *slower*. I would like to know why and what I can do to make the parallel for-loop much faster than the seriell for-loop.

Here is my code, where I compare both, the standard for-loop and the parallelized one using the multiprocessing module.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.special import expit

def regression_loss(W, k, x, y):
    U = expit(x.dot(W[k].T)) - y
    return np.sum(U*U)

def optimizer_seriell(p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W):
    loss = np.zeros((p_size))
    x, y = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_input), np.random.rand(batch_size, n_classes) 
    for k in range(p_size):
        loss[k] = regression_loss(W, k, x, y)

def optimizer_parallel(p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)
    x, y = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_input), np.random.rand(batch_size, n_classes) 
    loss = [pool.apply(regression_loss, args=(W, k, x, y)) for k in range(p_size)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p_size = 32
    n_classes = 10
    n_input = 1000
    batch_size = 8
    W = [np.random.rand(n_classes, n_input) for k in range(p_size)]

    t0 = time.time()
    optimizer_seriell(p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W)
    print(time.time()-t0) # 0.00186 on my machine

    t0 = time.time()
    optimizer_parallel(p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W)
    print(time.time()-t0) # 0.20029 on my machine
```

Comment: [`apply` is blocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply). Use `apply_async`.

Comment: @AlexR Is `apply_async` still ordered?

Comment: What do you mean by ordered?

Comment: It's worth noting that even once you get this code to not be blocking, it may still run slower.  The reason is that creating a new process has significant overhead, and the amount of processing happening in each loop is not really that much.

Comment: Is there a reason you're going for multiprocessing? I don't think with a processing time that short there is much value in doing multiprocessing. You have to consider if its better given the overheads of multiprocessing, i.e. spin up, memory. Also how many cores does your PC have? if ncores < processes. There will be competition and a significant slowdown.

Comment: @Turksarama Is there another way I could go that would reduce the overhead?

Comment: @JasonChia The actual problem is much bigger and I show here just a minimal working example.

Comment: @Samuel you might want to split your process into 4 (or however many cores you have) and get each process to do one quarter of the whole, then join them together at the end.  This way you're only spooling up 4 processes instead of 32.

Comment: @AlexR I mean if the different losses are still in the same order as in the seriell for-loop aproach.

Comment: @Turksarama I though I was doing that by using `pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)`. What do I have to change then?

Comment: @Samuel Ah actually you're right, that does mean you'll only have 4 processes.  This actually means your problem is worse because that's a speedup not available to you.

You should try this with n > 1000 rather than 32 to see how the speedup works for actually large numbers of calculations.

Comment: @Samuel "The actual problem is much bigger" How much bigger? Keep in mind that ``multiprocessing`` actually has to copy data *to* and *from* processes back to the main process. Speeding up the computation by just a factor 4 is useless if copying needs just 3 times as long as the computation (and it probably takes way longer).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi By bigger I mean that `p_size` is in the order of 100 or 1000. Is there another approach I could go?

Answer (score 0):

I did some of my own tests and here are the results. I think you'd want pool.map instead of apply, particularly if you want to maintain order.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.special import expit

def regression_loss(test):#a little lazy to work out how to pass multiple variables
    W = test[0]
    k = test[1]
    x = test[2]
    y = test[3]
    U = expit(x.dot(W[k].T)) - y
    time.sleep(1) #simulate lots of hard work
    return np.sum(U*U)

def optimizer_seriell(x,y,p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W):
    loss = np.zeros((p_size))

    for k in range(p_size):
        loss[k] = regression_loss((W, k, x, y))



def optimizer_parallel(x,y,p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W):
    with mp.Pool(processes = 4) as pool:

        loss = [pool.map(regression_loss,[(W,k,x,y) for k in range(p_size)])]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p_size = 32
    n_classes = 10
    n_input = 1000
    batch_size = 8
    W = [np.random.rand(n_classes, n_input) for k in range(p_size)]
    x, y = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_input), np.random.rand(batch_size, n_classes) 
    t0 = time.time()
    optimizer_seriell(x,y,p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W)
    print(time.time()-t0) 

    t0 = time.time()
    optimizer_parallel(x,y,p_size, n_classes, n_input, batch_size, W)
    print(time.time()-t0)
```

this results in:
32.018938064575195 for serial
9.142435073852539 for parallel (obvious timesave if each loop takes 1 second to process)

When I tried it with apply as you did, there was no time save at all. This is because apply is blocking even in the iterable. I.e. no parallel processing actually happens.

What you are showing isnt actually an issue with multiprocessing, but the overhead cost overshadow the benefits.

EDIT: WIth apply
SErial -> 32.02 seconds
Parallel -> 34.04 #no parallel processing actually happened

Comment: @Samuel, did you ever solve the issue? I think this answer kinda shows that the total processing time of 0.018 seconds is negligible for the actual "processing" section. You might want to profile your code and see where it is taking the most time and then determine if multiprocessing can help you. Try cprofile and snakeviz